# SQL database #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: database, percentage, mysql-error-1242

I have error

> 1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

in

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM attendance GROUP BY stu_ID   ) /(SELECT COUNT(if(`attstatus`='P', `attstatus`,NULL)) 
FROM attendance  GROUP BY stu_ID
```

How can I solve it and any other solution can show percentage for `attstatus='P'`?

```
SELECT stu_ID,stu_name,

GROUP_CONCAT(if(class_no="lec_1", `attstatus`, NULL)) AS 'Lecturer 1',

GROUP_CONCAT(if(class_no="lec_2", `attstatus`, NULL)) AS 'Lecturer 2',

COUNT(if(`attstatus`='P', `attstatus`,NULL)) AS 'total p',

COUNT(if(`attstatus`='A', `attstatus`, NULL)) AS 'total a',

COUNT(*) as dayTotal,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM attendance GROUP BY stu_ID   ) /(SELECT COUNT(if(`attstatus`='P', `attstatus`,NULL)) FROM attendance  GROUP BY stu_ID) 



FROM attendance 

WHERE session_ID=1

GROUP BY stu_ID,stu_name;
```

Comment: Probably you should post these questions as separate questions (with links to the other if it makes sense). For the first problem, it seems the first `GROUP BY` causes the problems. It might help if you describe what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Gábor Bakos so sorry..caused by GROUP BY..i would calculate the percentage of total p by using total p/daytotal

Answer (score -1):

Try adding to your sql : **LIMIT 1**
It will return only one row